# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los id's borrados de varios botones en una sola variable?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo obtener los id's borrados de varios botones en una sola variable? pero el problema que tengo es que si es un array al pasar de un modal a otro es como que si el array no se limpiara y se clonara por lo cual no encuentro manera de solucionarlo, ayuda por favor. Si conocen una mejor forma de almacenar múltiples id´s en una sola variable al ser cliqueadas en el boton de eliminar seria de mucha ayuda muchas gracias. Esto quiero hacerlo para pasar esas id´s a una solicitud ajax que recibe un controlador en codeigniter.

**Este es el modal donde lo llamo con un evento en javascript**

```
<div id="modalEditarOtPloteo"
     class="modal fade"
     tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Editar Orden de Trabajo Ploteo</h5>
                <button type="button"
                        class="close"
                        data-dismiss="modal">&times;
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action=""
                      method="post"
                      id="formularioPloteo">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="editarTipoDocumentoPloteo">Tipo de Documento</label>
                            <select id="editarTipoDocumentoPloteo"
                                    name="editarTipoDocumentoPloteo"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    data-fouc
                                    required
                                    disabled="disabled">
                                <?php foreach ($tipoDocumentoPloteo as $documento): ?>
                                    
                                    <option value="<?= $documento->ID_Documento ?>"><?= $documento->Nombre_Documento
                                        ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </select>
                            <input type="hidden"
                                   id="editarDataDocumentoPloteo"
                                   name="editarDataDocumentoPloteo">
                            <input type="hidden"
                                   id="editarIdDocumentoPloteo"
                                   name="editarIdDocumentoPloteo">
                            <input type="hidden"
                                   id="editarImpuestoDocumentoPloteo"
                                   name="editarImpuestoDocumentoPloteo">
                            <input type="hidden"
                                   id="editarIdOtPloteo"
                                   name="editarIdOtPloteo">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label for="editarSerieDocumentoPloteo">Serie</label>
                            <input type="text"
                                   name="editarSerieDocumentoPloteo"
                                   id="editarSerieDocumentoPloteo"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   disabled>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label for="editarNumeroDocumentoPloteo">Número</label>
                            <input type="text"
                                   name="editarNumeroDocumentoPloteo"
                                   id="editarNumeroDocumentoPloteo"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   disabled>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="editarClientePloteo">Cliente</label>
                        <select id="editarClientePloteo"
                                name="editarClientePloteo"
                                class="form-control select-search"
                                data-placeholder="Seleccione un cliente"
                                data-fouc
                                required>
                            <option></option>
                            <?php foreach ($clientePloteo as $value): ?>
                                
                                <option value="<?= $value->ID_Cliente ?>"><?= $value->Nombre_Cliente . ' ' . $value->Apellido_Cliente ?></option>'
                            
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <label for="editarMetrosPloteo">Metros de Ploteo</label>
                            <input type="text"
                                   name="editarMetrosPloteo"
                                   id="editarMetrosPloteo"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   placeholder="1.75">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7 align-self-end text-right">
                            <button href="#"
                                    id="editarAgregarPloteo"
                                    class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-icon"
                                    type="button"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Agregar
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered tablaEditarAgregarPloteo">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Metros</th>
                                        <th>Precio Final</th>
                                        <th>Acción</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label for="editarSubtotalPloteo">Subtotal:</label>
                            <input type="text"
                                   class="input form-control"
                                   name="editarSubtotalPloteo"
                                   id="editarSubtotalPloteo"
                                   readonly
                                   required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label for="editarIvaPloteo">IVA:</label>
                            <input type="text"
                                   class="input form-control"
                                   name="editarIvaPloteo"
                                   id="editarIvaPloteo"
                                   readonly
                                   required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label for="editarTotalPloteo">Total:</label>
                            <input type="text"
                                   class="input form-control"
                                   name="editarTotalPloteo"
                                   id="editarTotalPloteo"
                                   readonly
                                   required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button class="btn bg-primary-800"
                                type="button"
                                id="editarOrdenTrabajoPloteo">Editar Orden de Trabajo <i
                                    class="icon-paperplane
                                    ml-2"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Este es el javascript con todos los eventos**

```
/* EDITAR ORDEN DE TRABAJO PLOTEO */

$(document).on('click', '#editarOtPloteo', function (event) {
    
    event.preventDefault()
    
    let idEditarOtPloteo = $(this).attr('value')
    // alert(idEditarOtPloteo)
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/ci3/ploteo/editar',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            idEditarOtPloteo: idEditarOtPloteo
        },
        success: function (data) {
            
            
            // console.log(metros)
            /* IMPRESION DE LOS VALORES EN CADA INPUT DEL MODAL EDITAR ORDEN DE TRABAJO PLOTEO */
            $('#editarIdOtPloteo').val(data.post[0].ID_OTPloteo)
            $('#editarIdDocumentoPloteo').val(data.post[0].ID_Documento)
            $('#editarImpuestoDocumentoPloteo').val(data.post[0].Impuesto_Documento)
            $('#editarTipoDocumentoPloteo').val(data.post[0].ID_Documento).trigger('change')
            $('#editarSerieDocumentoPloteo').val(data.post[0].Serie_OTPloteo)
            $('#editarNumeroDocumentoPloteo').val(data.post[0].NumeroDocumento_OTPloteo)
            $('#editarClientePloteo').val(data.post[0].ID_Cliente).trigger('change')
            $('#editarSubtotalPloteo').val(data.post[0].Subtotal_OTPloteo)
            $('#editarIvaPloteo').val(data.post[0].Impuesto_OTPloteo)
            $('#editarTotalPloteo').val(data.post[0].Total_OTPloteo)
            
            /* LIMPIAR LA MINITABLA AL PASAR DE MODAL EN MODAL */
            $('.tablaEditarAgregarPloteo tbody').empty();
            
            /* RECORRER CADA DATO DE LA RESPUESTA DEL CONTROLADOR PARA IMPRIMIRLO EN LA MINITABLA */
            data.post[1].forEach(item => {
                // Crea contenido HTML de la fila
                // Agrega un campo oculto para saber qué es lo que se está modificando
                let html = `<tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="editarIdPloteo[]" value="${item.ID_OTPloteo}">
                                            <input type="text" name="editarMetrosTotalPloteo[]" class="editarMetrosTotalPloteo form-control" value="${item.Precio_OTPloteo}">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control editarImporteMetrosPloteo" name="editarImporteMetrosPloteo[]" value="${(item.Importe_OTPloteo)}" readonly>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="editarIdDetallePloteo[]" value="${(item.ID_DetalleOTPloteo)}">
                                            <button href="#" id="eliminarMetros" value="${(item.ID_DetalleOTPloteo)}" class="eliminarMetros btn btn-danger btn-icon" type="button"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>
                                        </td>
                                </tr>`;
                
                /* DIBUJO EN EL HTML DE LA TABLA CON LOS DATOS DE LA BASE DE DATOS */
                $('.tablaEditarAgregarPloteo').append(html);
                
            });
            
            /* AGREGAR FILAS A LA MINI TABLA EDITAR OT PLOTEO */
            $('#editarAgregarPloteo').on('click', function () {
                
                /* OBTENCION DEL VALOR DEL INPUT */
                let datos = $('#editarMetrosPloteo').val()
                
                if (datos != '') {
                    
                    /* PROCESO PARA AUMENTAR LAS FILAS EN LA TABLA PARA AGREGAR METROS */
                    tabla = `<tr>`;
                    tabla += `<td><input type="text" name="editarMetrosTotalPloteo[]" class="editarMetrosTotalPloteo form-control" value="${datos}"></td>`;
                    tabla += `<td><input type="text" class="form-control editarImporteMetrosPloteo" name="editarImporteMetrosPloteo[]" value="${(datos * 1.25).toFixed(2)}" readonly></td>`;
                    tabla += `<td><a href="#" id="eliminarMetros" value="" class="eliminarMetros btn btn-danger btn-icon" type="button"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>`;
                    tabla += `</tr>`;
                    
                    /* DIBUJAR LA TABLA EN LA TABLA RESPECTIVA EN EL HTML */
                    $('.tablaEditarAgregarPloteo').append(tabla);
                }
                
                /* LIMPIEZA DEL INPUT DESPUES DE AGREGAR LOS METROS */
                $('input[name=editarMetrosPloteo]').val('');
                editarCalculosMetrosPloteo()
            });
            
            $(document).on('keyup', '.tablaEditarAgregarPloteo input.editarMetrosTotalPloteo', function () {
                
                /* OBTENER EL VALOR DEL INPUT */
                let metros = $(this).val();
                // alert(metros)
                
                /* CALCULOS */
                let importe = (metros * 1.25).toFixed(2)
                
                /* IMPRESION EN EL INPUT READONLY DE LA COLUMNA DE IMPORTES */
                $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').children('input').val(importe)
                editarCalculosMetrosPloteo()
            })
            /* ELIMINACION INDIVIDUAL DE LOS METROS CUANDO LA TABLA YA ESTA CREADA */
            $(document).on('click', '#eliminarMetros', function () {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove()
                editarCalculosMetrosPloteo()
            })
            
            
            let nuevometro = []
            $(document).on('click', '#eliminarMetros', function () {
                
                nuevometro.push($(this).val())
                console.log(nuevometro)
            })
            
            $('#modalEditarOtPloteo').modal('show');
            
        }
    })
    
})
```

A continuación subo un video de lo que me sucede cuando cambio de modales.

[Video del fallo en los modales y en los arrays](https://vimeo.com/450649688)

```js
let data = {
    "respuesta": "success",
    "post": [
        {
            "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
            "ID_Cliente": "3",
            "ID_Documento": "2",
            "Subtotal_OTPloteo": "23.75",
            "Impuesto_OTPloteo": "2.85",
            "Total_OTPloteo": "26.60",
            "NumeroDocumento_OTPloteo": "000140",
            "Serie_OTPloteo": "001",
            "Fecha_OTPloteo": "2020-08-19 21:45:12",
            "Nombre_Cliente": "David Alejandro",
            "Apellido_Cliente": "Paucar Briones",
            "Telefono_Cliente": "0992896820",
            "Nombre_Documento": "Factura",
            "Impuesto_Documento": "12",
            "Cantidad_Documento": "141",
            "Serie_Documento": "001",
            "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "30",
            "Precio_OTPloteo": "3.00",
            "Importe_OTPloteo": "3.75"
        },
        [
            {
                "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "30",
                "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                "Precio_OTPloteo": "3.00",
                "Importe_OTPloteo": "3.75"
            },
            {
                "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "31",
                "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                "Precio_OTPloteo": "7.00",
                "Importe_OTPloteo": "8.75"
            },
            {
                "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "32",
                "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                "Precio_OTPloteo": "9.00",
                "Importe_OTPloteo": "11.25"
            }
        ]
    ]
}

// Recorre los datos
data.post[1].forEach(item => {
    // Crea contenido HTML de la fila
    // Agrega un campo oculto para saber qué es lo que se está modificando
    let html = `<tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="idPloteo[]" value="${item.ID_DetalleOTPloteo}">
            <input type="text" name="metrosTotalPloteo[]" class="metrosTotalPloteo form-control" value="${item.Precio_OTPloteo}">
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control importeMetrosPloteo" name="importeMetrosPloteo[]" value="${(item.Importe_OTPloteo)}" readonly></td>
        <td><a href="#" value="" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon eliminarMetros" type="button"><i class="icon-trash">Borrar</i></a></td>
    </tr>`;
    // Agrega fila a la tabla
    $('.tablaEditarAgregarPloteo').append(html);
});


$(document).on('click', '.eliminarMetros', function () {
    // Obtener fila a la que pertenece el botón
    let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        // Eliminar fila y volver a calcular
        $(tr).remove();
        // calculosMetrosPloteo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-bordered tablaEditarAgregarPloteo">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Metros</th>
                                        <th>Precio Final</th>
                                        <th>Acción</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Comment: Puedes incluir el codigo del modal con su respectivo script?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera listo ya subi mi codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás deberías crear un arreglo y luego, antes de eliminar la fila, agregar esta sentencia:

```
arreglo.push(tr.children().first().children()[0].value);
```

Al terminar, el arreglo contendrá todos los id deseados.